# Recommendations for handling HTML form data using PHP - and may Python?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, export

I am making a very simple HTML form using PHP.  I would like the form to execute:

1. Email input to user (done)
2. Export to an SQL database (I have the database set up)
3. Show the input on the page and have the option to download results as .csv and .pdf

Another question, what is the best practice:

1. Have the .php file uploaded to the FTP server (or)
2. Write the  php script in the HTML file?

Finally, would it be easier to write the php script in Python instead?

**Here's the php code:**

```
    <?php
$date = $_POST['date'];
$client = $_POST['client'];
$session = $_POST['session'];
$session_type = $_POST['session_type'];
$progress = $_POST['progress'];
$previous_session = $_POST['previous_session'];
$verbal = $_POST['verbal'];
$body_language = $_POST['body_language'];
$mood = $_POST['mood'];
$objective = $_POST['objective'];
$assessment = $_POST['assessment'];
$goals = $_POST['goals'];
$quotes = $_POST['quotes'];
$summary = $_POST['summary'];

$formcontent="Client name: $client \n
Date: $date \n
Meeting: $session \n
Session type: $session_type \n
Progress: $progress \n
Previous session: $previous_session \n
Verbal: $verbal \n
Body language: $body_language \n
Mood: $mood \n
Objective: $objective \n
Assessment: $assessment \n
Goals: $goals \n
Client quotes: $quotes \n
Summary of session: $summary";
$recipient = "maryknauth@mac.com";
$subject = "Case notes for $client on $date";
$mailheader = "From: mySportPsych Admin \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You, the case notes submitted have been emailed to $recipient and are also listed below:\n
Client name: $client\n
Date: $date\n
Meeting: $meeting\n
Session type: $session_type\n
Progress: $progress\n
Previous session: $previous_session\n
Verbal: $verbal\n
Body language: $body_language\n
Mood: $mood\n
Objective: $objective\n
Assessment: $assessment\n
Goals: $goals\n
Client quotes: $quotes\n
Summary of session: $summary";?>
```

**Here is the HTML form:**

```
        <form action="case_notes.php" method="post">
     <h4 class="text-form-section">Overview</h4>
        <hr class="style-hr">
     <!-- Date -->  
    <label for="date" class="label">Date</label>
        <br>
    <input name="date" type="date" class="input-text" id="date">
        <br>
<!-- Client --> 
    <label for="client" class="label">Client</label>
        <br>
    <input name="client" type="text" class="input-text" id="client">
        <br>
<!-- Session -->
<!-- Is this supposed to be a number? -->
    <label for="session" class="label">Session</label>
        <br>
    <input name="session" type="text" class="input-text" id="session">
        <br>
<!-- Type of Session -->
    <label for="session_type" class="label">Session Type</label>
        <br>
        <select name="session_type" id="session_type">
            <option value="null"></option>
            <option value="free">Free Consultation</option>
            <option value="initial">Initial Consultation</option>
            <option value="regular">Regular Consultation</option>
            <option value="termination">Termination</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>   
        <br>

<!-- Progress -->
    <label for="progress" class="label">Progress</label>
        <br>
        <select name="progress" id="progress">
            <option value="null"></option>
            <option value="very_good">Very Good</option>
            <option value="good">Good</option>
            <option value="none">No Progress</option>
            <option value="regression">Regression</option>
        </select>   

      <br>
        <br>
<!-- Previous session review -->    
    <label for="previous_session" class="label">Previous session review</label>
        <br>
    <input name="previous_session" type="textarea" class="input-text" id="previous_session" rows="5" cols="30">
        <br>
 <!-- Subject Review -->
    <div class="subject review">    
    <h4 class="text-form-section">Subject</h4>
        <hr class="style-hr">
    <label for="verbal" class="label">Verbal</label>
        <br>
    <input name="verbal" type="textarea" class="input-text" id="verbal" rows="5" cols="30">
        <br>
    <label for="body_language" class="label">Body Language</label>
        <br>
    <input name="body_language" type="textarea" class="input-text" id="body_language" rows="5" cols="30">
        <br>
    <label for="mood" class="label">Mood</label>
        <br>
    <input name="mood" type="textarea" class="input-text" id="mood" rows="5" cols="30">
    </div>
    <h4 class="text-form-section">Session Review</h4>
        <hr class="style-hr">
    <label for="objective" class="label">Objective</label>
        <br>
    <input name="objective" type="textarea" class="input-text" id="objective" rows="5" cols="30">   
        <br>

    <label for="assessment" class="label">Assessment</label>
        <br>
    <input name="assessment" type="textarea" class="input-text" id="assessment" rows="5" cols="30">
        <br>

    <label for="goals" class="label">Goals</label>
        <br>
    <input name="goals" type="textarea" class="input-text" id="goals" rows="5" cols="30">
        <br>

    <label for="quotes" class="label">Client Quotes</label>
        <br>
    <input name="quotes" type="textarea" class="input-text" id="quotes" rows="5" cols="30">
        <br>

    <label for="summary" class="label">Summary</label>
        <br>
    <input name="summary" type="textarea" class="input-text" id="summary" rows="5" cols="30">
        <br>
        <br>

    <input type="submit" class="button">

</form>
```

Comment: have you tried anything? Or you think we will make it for you? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should ask your questions one at a time for most people (including me) to understand them easily. We want to help. Keep your question simple and clear for everybody

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not able to see any `<input> field for Email` in your form. To email the user you should receive the email address from the user via a form. Right? Also, you have used your email address as `recipient` in the `mail()` function. Once you add the Email field in the form do not forget to validate the email before assigning into `mail()`.
2. I assume you need to insert the form data into the Database. For that, you should create a DB connection with PHP and INSERT into the Database table with SQL Queries.
3. Showing the Data on the page is simple and I can relate this to your other question `Write the PHP script in the HTML file?`. You can't run a PHP Script in an HTML file but the other way around. You can write HTML in a PHP script! So you can combine both above files into a single PHP File or you can split the form in an HTML file and process the request in a PHP file and output the Form Data in a Table (After DB Insertion, Mail etc).

> would it be easier to write the PHP script in Python instead

No. you can't write PHP in a python file or if you mean whether you should write in Python. It's completely upto you. I would say PHP is easier to begin with but harder to master. So do the basics right, understand the concepts clear and well. Also, understand the related technology (HTTP, Mail) and their working clearly.

Lastly, take your time and build knowledge slow and steady.

Following links will help you learn that:

[PHP MySQL INTRODUCTION](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

[PHP MySQL INSERT](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

[PHP Form Handling](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-form-handling.php)